# Permissions Hook?

Tags: entities, users

I have a lot of user-generated content that I want to restrict to only be viewed by 'in-network' peers. I was originally trying to use Organic Groups but it's way more functionality than I need and I couldn't use it across all the entities I wanted to. Also, I could never get the [og_subgroups](https://drupal.org/project/og_subgroups) module to work right, and there's a hierarchical element to the rules, too.

If I just want to implement my own permissions logic, I'd use `hook_node_grants`, right? Is there an equivalent for entities or other objects?

Comment: Nodes have a solid access restriction system built in but for other core, contrib or custom entities, the access systems can vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet that allow users(particular role/roles) to access nodes based on content type.

```
  function HOOK_node_access($node, $op, $account){
    if (is_string($node))
        return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;

    if ($node->type == 'my_type' && $op == 'view'){
        $allowed_roles = array(
            'authenticated user'
        );
        $access_allow = array_intersect($allowed_roles, array_values($account->roles));
        if ($access_allow)
            return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
        else
            return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
    }
    return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a somewhat shameful self promotion. 
I too had a similar requirement but I was not willing to implement any expensive hooks just to hide some nodes.

Try this sandbox module: https://drupal.org/sandbox/ayesh/2274655

It allows you to select one or more node types and one or more roles to *allow* access to them. 
It doesn't support any fancy UIs or per-operation permissions but this would be a good starting point I think.

Works in individual node pages, search pages (non-admins won't see results from private node types), term pages, views, etc.